# Sharepoint BI Learning = where?

Tags: business-intelligence, bi

Where can I find video material to learn about Sharepoint BI? I'm newbie in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure by what you want or want to learn but I assume you are looking for some tutorials for Development of Business Intelligence dashboard in SharePoint,

[This hour's Youtube tutorial might be able to help you.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22pwJiuMtBE)

If you want to read MSDN documentation which I prefer then here's the [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877811%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: You (correctly) flag it as a Wiki Q, so why dont you a) flag your Answer as CW, b) comment on user to accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good links:

[Free Online PerformancePoint Services 2010 Training Videos](http://denglishbi.wordpress.com/2010/04/17/free-online-performancepoint-services-2010-training-videos/)
[Module 8: Business intelligence SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff420385.aspx)
[SharePoint 2010 Business Intelligence Virtual Lab](http://denglishbi.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/sharepoint-2010-business-intelligence-virtual-lab/)

I hope these are helpful too!

Answer (score 0):

For sharepoint bi you can look at msdn as one very good place to start:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262880.aspx

for the BI part:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573016.aspx

for a list of tut on youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3B7C33AB2CC9CA28

hope it helps :)